# Canonical method for providing run-time parameters to all classes -- global?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

What's the canonical C++ design pattern for solving this kind of problem?

I've got a some multi-threaded servers which share a number of classes.  I need to make a variety of run-time parameters (e.g. server name, logging level) available to the majority of the classes.

In the below pseudo-C++ code, I use a logging class's parameters as one such example, but there may be other values which need to be accessed in the various objects.

In particular, the Thread objects need to have their own instances of the log class to avoid corruption.

I could make the run-time parameters global, or static, but those both seem to have code smell.  Likewise a singleton or passing the values around to many constructors or initializers seems non-optimal or breaks the Law of Demeter.

The Thread class within the Server class (below) is not something I can change at this point, despite that it may be getting in the way of something more elegant.  :-/

Pardon the quick and dirty C++ code below; hopefully it adequately illustrates the problem.

```
// p1.cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Log log(level, "p1");
    Driver driver;
    driver.exec(new p1Factory());
}
// p2.cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Log log(level, "p2");
    Driver driver;
    driver.exec(new p2Factory());
}
// p3 ... p7.cpp same as above

class Driver {
public:
    Driver() {}
    void exec(GenericFactory * f) { factory = f; server.createThreads(); }
protected:
    GenericFactory * factory;
    Server server(GenericFactory * f);
};

class Server : public GenericServer {
protected:
    class Thread : public IPCThread
    {
        friend class Server;
    private:
        Channel * channel;
        Log threadLog;
    public:
        Thread(Channel * c);
    };

    GenericFactory * factory;

public:
    Server(GenericFactory * f);
    void createThreads();
};

Server::createThreads() {
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; ++i) {
        thread[i] = new Server::Thread(factory->getChannel());
        // I need to set the threadLog's level and ident string to the
        // same values they had in the top-level global log.  How?
    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion singleton is ok here. Law of Demeter is about implemenation concealment, not data that should be available in vast majority of classes, mm?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a *canonical* method, but here are some techniques.

**Store as global variables**
Copy the values into global variables.  Supply the variable names in header files as `extern`.

**Pass the parameters to each function requiring the variables**
Some people against Singletons say to pass the variables to all the functions that require them.

**Store in a configuration function / class**
You could create a `Configuration` singleton that reads and parses the command line.  This entity would have methods to read the parameters, but not write them.

Sorry, but I don't see a "one size fits all" method.  Select one and go with it.  Roll the dice or flip a coin if you can't decide.